# Drupal 7 questionnaire webform

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

What is the best method to create a questionnaire in drupal 7?
We use multiple choice questions. (+/- 20)

Is it possible to have one question per page? How?

Is there a way to give the user the end-score of this questionnaire? How?

Comment: limesurvey and limesurvey_sync module

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Add a content type "Test1"

- To the Test1, add a Text field, "Question1"
- Also, add a List (text) field, enter

  - q1|Answer one
  - q2|Answer two
- Repeat for more questions

Use Field Group module to divide questions by pages.

To take the test, add Test1 "`/node/add/test1`".

To create an answer sheet, take the test and use the Node ID of the test for the next step.

Create a view, using Views. Match any taken test against the Node Id of the answer sheet. You can do so, by including a link at the end of the test, which links to "`/score/%NID%`", `%NID%` being the Node ID of the current TEST1. Create a page in views, with "`/score/%`" as a path. Use the Contextual Filter to get the NID from the path and match it against the NID of the cheat sheet.

You can get it more advanced by using referencing fields, via [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'll give it a try this week and let you know! Thanks!